# how to delete multiple records from database ( using laravel 5.5)

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I am trying to delete multiple records from database but I am currently unable to do that. I can only delete first record from the database and I am using postman for my request.

My Code:

```
Route::post('delete_page',function(Request $request) {

    $all_data = $request->all();

    foreach($all_data as $id) {
        \App\Page::where('id',$id)->delete();
    }
});
```

I am passing my value from postman like this:
form-data:

```
key is: array[id] and value is any id that is 3
key is: array[id] and value is any id that is 4
```

If I hit my request it only deletes the record with id 3, but I want to delete multiple records. How can I do that?

Your help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried debugging your problem? What does `$all_data` contain? What happens instead? Is there any error message given?

Comment: its showing array:1 [
  "array" => array:1 [
    "id" => "3"
  ]
]

Comment: when i dd($all_data)

Comment: So, obviously, your array is malformed

Comment: whats solution?

Comment: Use a proper array. The given one looks really strange and doesn't even contain other IDs than 3

Comment: can u please modilfy

Comment: How should I know how your application generates `$all_data`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

$ids = [1, 2, 3, 4];

\App\Page:: whereIn('id',$ids)->delete();